# Looking for a PE Unpacker

Tags: portable-executable

What is the best way to unpack PE files?  I've seen some tools from 7 years ago, like Quick Unpack.  Is there anything more recent?  Or is it better to run different tools for different packers since individual unpackers are likely more up-to-date?

Comment: senseless question. what you mean under "unpack" ? and in all case can not be any universal tool for this.

Comment: @RbMm, what happens when I run "upx -d" on a UPX-packed PE if not unpacking?   Wasn't Quick Unpack exactly an attempt to create a universal unpacker?  Why can't there be another one?  If you are an expert in the field, please share your knowledge; calling questions "senseless" and making unsubstantiated claims does not help anyone.

Comment: we can unpack some **known** format like UPX. can not be universal "unpacker". impossible unpack unknown format

Comment: @RbMm, sorry, I don't understand your point.  I am trying to automate the process.  Of course, I am not trying to guess the format, try to break the likes of Themida, etc.  Still, I've done some statistics and seen that a large fraction of executables on VT can realistically be unpacked - and I want to go after those.  My question is whether this can be done with a single tool, such as Quick Unpack, but newer and better, or (looks like) I should just get a bunch of tools - one per packer - and try them one by one.

Comment: if exe packed by some know algoritm, like UPX - we can unpack it. we can try some known set of most popular format test/unpack. but in general case - task is impossible - binary can be arbitrarily "packed" (this word also not very specific - are you under "packed" mean any PE which modify self code in runtime ?) and can not be any universal tool for this.

Comment: This is tagged incorrectly with packer. Removed

Answer (score 1):

There is no one size fits all solution.

The latest "all in one" unpackers are [Quick Unpack](http://qunpack.ahteam.org/) and GUnpacker but they are both getting rather old.

There is [Pe-sieve](https://hshrzd.wordpress.com/pe-sieve/) & [mal_unpack](https://github.com/hasherezade/mal_unpack) from hasherezade, mal_unpack can work in an automated fashion.  Mal_unpack is basically just an automated version of Pe-sieve. Pe-bear is another tool from hasherezade which helps you re-align sections after doing a dump, which requires that you know how to unpack manually but it make the process much easier.

There is a new online tool for unpacking malware called [unpac.me](https://www.unpac.me) from the OpenAnalysis team which can unpack just about anything.

Successful malware distributors are not using public crypters as often, heuristics for detecting public packers is too easy, which is why we have seen a reduction in AIO unpacker tools.  In addition, Themida and VMProtect are the standard now and as they continue to add more features, they're becoming more difficult to unpack everyday.  With the new virtualization features, automated unpacking is becoming almost impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Even though Quick Unpack is old, I would not underestimate its power in present days. As long as you find the best setup, this tool will produce launchable dumps of Exes/Dlls packed by dozens of known packers + even unknown ones!

Make sure you are running an old OS (WinXP - 7) really or virtually, and don't forget that Quick Unpack is a dynamic unpacker (i.e. can hardly be used for malware analysis). Old does not mean bad :)

This concerns packers in their classical definition.
If you are looking for some "generic unpacker" for modern protectors (such as VMProtect, Themida, Enigma, Obsidium, etc.), then I do not think they will ever be made. There are some specific tools (both private and public) which can help you to automate "unpacking" partially, but the majority of work still needs to be done by hands to remove these kinds of protectors. But again, it depends on what you want to see in the end (analysable code, de-obfuscated dump, fully launchable reconstruct, ...).